# Payday: The Heist language problen

Tags: payday-the-heist

For some reason Payday in a language I don't know. Can someone send me something like a layout of the settings menu and stuff so I can set it to English?

Comment: HOW did you get it free? Was it some Friend who give it to you per Harddrive etc? Or was it a Steam Present? Illegal Download? Reminder: we won't help you with Illegal Software!

Comment: @Serverfrog Months ago PAYDAY 2 had an event that allowed everyone to download PAYDAY: The Heist for free. I think he claimed it but hadn't tried it until now. He should indeed state it in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you possess the game legally, you need to have linked it to a steam account. Changing the language can be done in the steam overlay by right clicking the game and going to the language tab (See [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8487-WSCN-4121)).

If you do not have linked the game to steam then we won't help you since I do not believe that to be legal.